# Generating a random real number between 100 and 200 using the random function in Python

Tags: python, random

How can I generate a random real number between 100 and 200 using the random function in Python? The default range is 0-1

Comment: Have you [checked the section on real values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#real-valued-distributions) in the `random` documentation yet?

Comment: @Biohacker x100 +100

Comment: @Guimoute Thanks, works well.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the random library

```
import random
print(random.randrange(100,200))
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. In fact, I wanted a function that could generate either an integer or a float. Thus, a real number in general.